# Get schema and options in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In a particular API that is used to manage production data for the visual effects and animation industry, there is a call in the python API to get the available fields for an entity (a model basically). I am looking at trying to get the same things from my Rest API to dynamically add new or remove attributes to a react frontend with the correct field types.

Does something like this already exist in DRF or will I need to create a custom view to get this data from the meta on the model?

An example response may be something like...

```
{model: {
    field1: {
        type: "charField",
        choices: ["A", "B", "C"],
        default: "A",
        required: True
    },
    field2: {
        type: "boolField",
        default: True,
        required: False
    }
}
```

Thanks!

The Example API I mentioned:
https://developer.shotgridsoftware.com/python-api/reference.html#shotgun_api3.shotgun.Shotgun.schema_field_read

** Edit **

I was able to create my own custom viewset to do this that I have my other viewsets inheriting. It would be good to know if DRF has something like this already.

rest_views.py

```
class SchemaQueryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=False)
    def schema(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class()
        field_data = {}
        for field_name, field_obj in serializer.fields.items():
            field_data[field_name] = {
                "field_type": str(field_obj).split("(")[0],
                "read_only": field_obj.read_only,
                "required": field_obj.required,
                "label": field_obj.label
            }
            if hasattr(field_obj, "valid_formats"):
                field_data[field_name]["valid_formats"] = field_obj.valid_formats
    return Response(field_data)


class ProjectViewSet(SchemaQueryViewset):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

There was no need to update the URLS, the /schema endpoint showed up automatically when using the rest framework router.